# preg_match pattern check that strin contain only letters,whitespace and dot

Tags: php, preg-match

The code below shows a simple way to check if the name field only contains letters and whitespace. If the value of the name field is not valid, then store an error message:

```
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
{
$nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}
```

My question is how I can add dot (.) in here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange this line:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
```

with this line:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\. ]*$/", $name))
```

You have to escape the `.` character, as it has special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: No problem. Note that you can also shorten this to: `!preg_match('/^[a-z\. ]*$/i', $name)` - the '`i`' flag makes the expression case-insensitive. You also might want to be aware that your current regular expression will match an empty string - the `*` character at the end means 'zero or more', so matching nothing is completely valid.

Comment: I'm pretty confident the regular expression is correct. What exactly does the `test_input` method do?

Comment: ok ok , i solve it , i need to change pattern on two places , now its working fine . thanks

Comment: You don't actually have to escape the dot inside of a character class, unless you're using it as your delimiter (which you shouldn't be).  Consider matching a literal `.com` in a domain.  If you used this `if (preg_match('/[.]com/', $string)){`, the string `google.com` would match, but `googleZcom` would not.  It will, of course, not hurt anything to escape the character, but really only square braces and delimiters need to be escaped inside of a character class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z \.]*$/";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always add a . in the square brackets. For example the expression [a-zA-Z.] is correct and will give you the thing you want i.e. a list of characters to be checked. If you want to check for . outside the [] then escape the . like . Also your code does not check for tabs which is whitespace. So you should add \s instead of ' '. Similarly there are a lot of other special characters such as ? which will be considered normal characters in the [] brackets. One exception is the - which has to be always added at the end i.e. [A-Z?-]. There are however still some special characters that have to escaped such as "'/. My advice is run the expression online to check first before inserting it into your code. Regex errors are very common and very difficult to find. Your expression should be :-

```
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z.\s]+$/",$name)) {
 $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }
```

Cheers!